# Print out GLOB() instead of variable name

Tags: perl

I have defined and opened a file name as:

```
open my $file1, '<', 'test_dll.txt';
```

Now when I am calling it and want to say that for example print the name of file it prints out `GLOB()` instead of `test_dll.txt`.

```
print "The name of file is: $file1\n";
```

Output:

```
The name of file is: GLOB(0x389e74)
```

Would one please let me know why this happens? and how could I have the name of variable?

Comment: Note: filehandles do not necessarily point to files; they could point to external commands or sockets, etc... As far as I know there is no *direct* way of doing what you are asking, there are several roundabout ways of doing this though: 1) Maintain a listing of files you create by name in a hash 2) Use [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) to find the inode of the file and use another tool to look up metadata about that inode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument to [open](http://p3rl.org/open) is a file handle, not the file name. If you want to keep the filename in a variable, use a separate one:

```
my $filename = 'test_dll.txt';
open my $FH, '<', $filename or die $!;
print "The name of file is: $filename\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you did

```
# Create a file handle and assign it to $file1.
open my $file1, '<', 'test_dll.txt';
```

instead of

```
# Assign a string to $file1.
my $file1 = 'test_dll.txt';
```